# Wrap Insert Statement in single quotes MS Access, setting default vlaues

Tags: ms-access

I have a insert statement in MS Access which needs to be wrapped in single quotes so that it can be passed as string to a column in another table.  here is my insert statement below

Insert into Employee(EmpName,EmpDepartment) Values ('Mike',NULL)

when I wrap I am getting errors arounf 'Mike'

'Insert into Employee(EmpName,EmpDepartment) Values ('Mike',NULL)'

Below is my create table with two primary keys

create table Employee([OBJECTID] AUTOINCREMENT(1, 1), EmpName Text(10), EmpDepartment Text(50), Primary Key (OBJECTID, EmpName))

How can I set default values to EmpName as Mike and Null to EmpDepartment while creating table it self ??

Comment: Do you want all employees to be called Mike? You can escape a quote by using 2: `'Insert into Employee(EmpName,EmpDepartment) Values (''Mike'',NULL)'`

Comment: No not all employees but need a default value to set in create table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need ADO to create a default easily with a standard SQL mode for Access. This will run in VBA.

```
sSQL = "create table Employee([OBJECTID] AUTOINCREMENT(1, 1), " _
     & "EmpName Text(10) default mike, EmpDepartment Text(50), " _
     & "Primary Key (OBJECTID, EmpName))"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute sSQL
```

Comment: Null as default for EmpDepartment -- ? is it like  EmpDepartment Text(50) default NULL

Comment: Null is the default for all text fields. What are you trying to get? `default NULL` would set the default to the word NULL.

Comment: I want a NULL value by default not word NULL -- so in this case  Should I use  EmpDepartment Text(50) default '' OR  EmpDepartment Text(50) default NULL or  not to use anything like default for EmpDepartment ?

Comment: Use nothing. The default for all text data types and most other data types *is* null.